# Watin search for text

Tags: c#-4.0, watin

I have a span element in my page:

```
<span class="selected-facets">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="?"> </a>
foo
</li>
</ul>
</span>
```

How can i write a test that makes sure that the

element in the span, contains the text 'foo'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside, a `ul` is a block level element so shouldn't be nested inside a`span`, which is an inline element

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help:

```
  browser.Span(Find.ByClass("selected-facets")).InnerHtml.Contains("Foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Mabye you should look here:
[Parsing-HTML-Tags-in-C](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57176/Parsing-HTML-Tags-in-C)

It seems relativly simple:

```
protected void Prossess(string html)
{
    HtmlTag tag;
    HtmlParser parse = new HtmlParser(html);
    while (parse.ParseNext("span", out tag))
    {
      string value;
      if (tag.Attributes.TryGetValue("class", out value))
      {
        // now should be able to compair the value
      }
    }
}
```

Or mabye this will be better for you:
[htmltidy](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/htmltidy.html)

Comment: I'm talking about watin and c# and not jquery

Comment: Sorry missed your tags before. Edited answer, mabye it will help.